# ERC20 token transfer to smart contract problem

Tags: solidity

I have problem on transfer USDT to Smart Contract .
Please help me.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

interface IERC20 {
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);

    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)
        external
        returns (bool);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(
        address sender,
        address recipient,
        uint256 amount
    ) external returns (bool);

    function increaseApproval(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);
    function decreaseApproval(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);



    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Approval(
        address indexed owner,
        address indexed spender,
        uint256 value
    );
}


contract SimpleBank{
    IERC20 tokenContract;

    constructor(IERC20 _tokenContract) public {
        tokenContract = _tokenContract;
    }


       function transfer(uint256 amount) external {
        address sender = msg.sender;
        address reciever = address(this);

        uint256 balance = tokenContract.balanceOf(sender);

        require(balance >= amount, "balance is low");

        bool success1 = tokenContract.approve(sender , amount);
        require(success1 , "error on approve");

        bool success = tokenContract.transferFrom(sender, reciever, amount);
        require(success, "transfer Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `approve()` function on the `tokenContract` needs to be invoked from the token sender directly - not through another contract.

---

Your snippet effectively approves `sender` to spend `SimpleBank`'s tokens, as `SimpleBank` is the `msg.sender` in the `tokenContract.approve()` function.

Comment: may I ask you send full transfer method for me?

Comment: could you please do it?

Comment: @FarhadVakilijamil Your snippet is going to work correctly after you've removed the `approve()` call (and the validation of `success1`) from your `transfer()` function... The user needs to send 2 transactions: 1) execute `approve(simpleBankAddress, amount)` on `tokenContract`. 2) execute `transfer(amount)` on `SimpleBank`.

Comment: I do it. but it does not work again.

Comment: function transfer(uint256 amount) external {
        address sender = msg.sender;
        address reciever = address(this);

        uint256 balance = tokenContract.balanceOf(sender);

        require(balance >= amount, "balance is low");

        bool success1 = tokenContract.approve(sender , amount);
        require(success1 , "error on approve");

        bool success = tokenContract.transfer(sender, amount);
        require(success, "transfer Error");
    }

Comment: Guys . Please help me. I can't find my issue About accept USDT in Smart Contract. Please answer me?